cooling system malfunctioning while using NixOS
My cooling system isn't functioning properly on NixOS. I checked the hardware monitor on MSI motherboard but I can't see anything which allows me to adjust fan settings.
how do I create a custom systemd service to control fan speeds based on temperature?
